# vector::insert in VS2010 performs unexpected result

Tags: c++, vector, reference, insert

I occasionally found a strange issue in VS2010 with next code:

```
void Test1()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(10);
    vec.push_back(20);
    vec.insert(vec.end(), vec[0]);
    // GCC: vec == [10, 20, 10];
    // VS2005: vec == [10, 20, 10];
    // VS2010: vec == [10, 20, -17891602];
}
```

It seems that vector reallocates memory and deletes the old one before reading a new value, that leads to copying of corrupted value. This issue is present in VS2010. Checked in VS2005 and GCC - OK.

Is it valid to pass to insert() a reference taken from operator[] or front()/back() methods?

**UPD:** Having done some investigations based on comments below, I came to a conclusion that using reserve() is not a good idea because of performance. It leads to unwanted big number of reallocations.

```
void Test2()
{
    std::vector<int> vec, vec2;
    const int count = 10000;
    int prevCap = 0, reallocCount = 0;
    int prevCap2 = 0, reallocCount2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (vec.size() >= vec.capacity())
        {
            vec.reserve(vec.size()+1);
        }
        vec.insert(vec.end(), i);
        vec2.insert(vec2.end(), i);
        const int cap = vec.capacity();
        const int cap2 = vec2.capacity();
        if (prevCap != cap) ++reallocCount;
        prevCap = cap;
        if (prevCap2 != cap2) ++reallocCount2;
        prevCap2 = cap2;
    }
    cout << reallocCount << " " << reallocCount2 << endl;
    // reallocCount == 10000, reallocCount2 == 15 GCC
}
```

So for now I have only two options:

1) use temporary variable

```
const int tempValue = vec[0];
vec.insert(vec.end(), tempValue);
```

But I'm not sure if tempValue can be removed by a compiler by some optimizations.

2) use push_back(0) and further pop_back() calls

```
vec.push_back(0);
vec.pop_back();
vec.insert(vec.end(), vec[0]);
```

This approach seems better, it gives an expected result and performance in VS2005/2010 and GCC.

Did I miss something? Is there a better solution?

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/copying-container-elements-from-the-c-li/240155771

Answer (score 4):

insert takes second argument by reference. op[] provides reference also. 
Calling insert invalidates references, so you have undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

The docs for [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) say (my emphasis)

> The vector is extended by inserting new elements before the element at
>   the specified position, effectively increasing the container size by
>   the number of elements inserted.
>
> **This causes an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space
>   if -and only if- the new vector size surpasses the current vector
>   capacity.**

Since the second argument to `insert` is a reference and reallocation may require a relocation of your heap cell, this suggests that your code is only safe if you know that reallocation cannot happen.  i.e. when `vec.capacity() > vec.size()`

As noted by Agnew and quetzalcoatl, there are a couple of ways you could fix your code

You could copy your new value to a temporary to ensure a reference to it remains valid

```
int val = vec[0];
vec.insert(vec.end(), val);
```

...or you could increase the capacity of your vector before calling `insert`

```
if (vec.capacity == vec.size()) {
    vec.reserve(vec.size()+1);
}
vec.insert(vec.end(), val);
```

Comment: Of course, this wouldn't be a problem if the reference returned by `vec[0]` was ever converted into a temporary before `insert` starts, but it's not.

Comment: Therefore, between usage like this, a [vector::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) should be used to ensure that no reallocation takes place during the insert: `vec.reserve(vec.size()+1); vec.insert(vec.end(), vec[0]);` is always safe. Well, at least until size+1 exceeds the memory ;)

Comment: @Angew, quetzalcoatl Thanks for the comments, I've updated my answer accordingly